# Azure Websites - Full Trust

Tags: azure

I thought it was announced a short while ago that full-trust was now allowed for an azure website deployment in reserved/standard mode. Is there something I need to do to enable support for full-trust?

Comment: It seems that they run in full trust but in a sand box where APIs are not allowed.  Not 100% sure but here's the thread:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/0b72a8bb-965f-435b-b096-7ed72fb47853/full-trust-web-site

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure Web Sites runs ASP.NET sites in full trust.  There is additional security hardening which is done on the servers regardless of the app framework being used, and that will limit whether or not some APIs work (e.g. you cannot format drives).

Comment: or apparently access GDI+